# Unable to launch Android Emulator on Windows 11 pro

Tags: windows, visual-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to run an Android emulator on my Windows 11 pro pc that supports virtualization.

When running the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator-check.exe" accel
```

I get this response:

```
accel:
0
Please disable Hyper-V before using the Android Emulator.  Start a command prompt as Administrator, run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot.WHPX (10.0.22000) is installed and usable.
accel
```

So then I run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off' I get the following response from the '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator-check.exe" accel' command:

```
accel:
6
HAXM is not installed on this machine
accel
```

This message means that it can't find any acceleration on the machine! It's going round in circles and it's driving my crazy!

Things I have checked:

I have enabled Virtualization from the BIOS

Correct windows features enabled-
[image]

Uninstalled HAXM from Android SDK manager-
[image]

Correct advancedFeatures.ini file-
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update VS to the latest version to resolve this issue.